# Iterative DFS to find path from source to destination

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

I would appreciate help debugging my implementation of DFS to find a path. My implementation generally works well but in a certain edge case will add an extra node to the result which is visited by the algorithm but should not included within the solution as a path from it to the next node in the result list does not exist. The issue is likely to be caused by where Result.add(nextNode) is positioned, but I have not been able to fix this bug.

An example of the problem is attached below (weights arbitrary), whereby the algorithm returns [0 2 4 1 3 5] as a result even though no edge from 4 to 1 exists.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpHTP.png)

Can anybody suggest how to modify my code so that a node like 4 is not added to the result please?

```
 public static ArrayList<Integer> pathDFS(Integer source, Integer destination, WeightedGraph graph) {
            ArrayList<Integer> Result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> Visited = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
            s.push(source);
            Visited.add(source);
            while (!s.isEmpty()) {
                Integer v = s.pop();
                    for (int nextNode : getAdjacentNodes(v, graph)) {
                        if (!Visited.contains(nextNode)) {
                            s.push(nextNode);
                            Visited.add(nextNode);
                            **Result.add(nextNode);**
                            if (nextNode == destination)
                                return Result;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Result;
        }
```

Comment: because DFS is not a very good graph traversal algorithm, it is probably the root of the problem. It isnt guaranteed to give you the best solution and therefore can come up with some weird stuff. (it could attempt to add it to the list because it thinks it leads to the end, but it doesnt) I would try to save a predeseccor of each *node* then retrace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the node to the `result` list every time you add it to `visited` list is clearly wrong (the set of visited nodes is not necessarily contains just the path. It can have a bunch of other nodes, not just one).

To fix it, you can create a `parent` list to store the parent of each node (and populate it when discover a new node). This way, you'd just need to go from the target node by the parent links to the source to reconstruct the path.